Rounding to nearest integer in the log domain
This is about the threshold of whether to round down to $N$ or round up to $N+1$ where the proportional rounding error (or the error in the log domain) is smallest.
What is the simplest way to prove
$$\begin{align}
\log(N) + \log\big(1 + \tfrac{1}{2N} \big) &= \\
\\
\log \big( N + \tfrac12 \big) &> \tfrac12 \big( \log(N) + \log(N+1) \big) \\
\\
  &= \log(N) + \tfrac12 \log \big( 1 + \tfrac1N \big) \\
\end{align}$$
or that
$$ \log\big(1 + \tfrac{1}{2N} \big) > \tfrac12 \log \big( 1 + \tfrac1N \big) $$
for any positive integer $N \in \mathbb{Z} > 0$ ?
I can sorta do it with L'Hopital's rule.  But there should be a simpler way.

Start from the inequality
$$  1 + {1 \over N} + {1 \over 4N^2} > 1 + {1 \over N}. $$
Factorize the left hand side to get
$$ \left( 1 + {1 \over 2N} \right)^2 > {1 + {1 \over N}}. $$
Take the square root of both sides to get
$$ 1 + {1 \over 2N} > \sqrt{1 + {1 \over N}} $$
and take logs.
Alternately, this follows from the well known AM-GM inequality applied to $1$ and $1 + 1/N$.

Thank you.  This is the answer.  I could just take logs of the 2nd inequality.  We don't need to square root.
